# Arduino Yun Disk Expander low memory but it looks like my memory is fine

Tags: arduino-yun

I can't quite understand this when I run arduino yun disk expander sketch with a sd card plugged in I get the the following message. You do not have enough flash memory need 1mb. I ssh into my arduino and I get this

```
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                    6.9M    632.0K      6.3M   9% /
/dev/root                 7.5M      7.5M         0 100% /rom
tmpfs                     29.8M    148.0K     29.7M   0% /tmp
tmpfs                     512.0K       0    512.0K   0% /dev
/dev/mtdblock3            6.9M    632.0K      6.3M   9% /overlay
overlayfs:/overlay        6.9M    632.0K      6.3M   9% /
/dev/sda1                29.7G      2.4M     29.7G   0% /mnt/sda1
```

The only thing that is full is the /dev/root but the reading I have done through the posts here and online say that's fine. Why may this be I am quite confused???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a YUN or a lot of experience with OpenWRT, so I'm not sure I'm going to be of much help but, I'm guessing the error you're seeing is from [this line](https://github.com/arduino/yun-go-updater/blob/1.3/YunDiskSpaceExpander/YunDiskSpaceExpander.ino#L156) of the sketch.

Excerpting that here:

```cpp
Process awk;

awk.runShellCommand(F("df / | awk '/overlay/ {print $4}'"));
int output = awk.parseInt();
if (output < 1000) {
  Serial.println(F("\nYou don't have enough disk space to install the utility software. You need to free at least 1MB of Flash memory.\nRetry!"));
  halt();
}
```

So, it appears they are executing `df / | awk '/overlay/ {print $4}'` on the YUN.

They're using [awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) to extract the fourth column (`$4`) of the line containing overlay (`/overlay/`), which by the way is awfully hackish.

Given that they expect the result of `awk.parseInt()` to compare less than `1000` to mean you have less than 1 Mbyte available, it's fairly clear they expected this column to be reported in kilobytes.  And yet in your own df listing

```
overlayfs:/overlay        6.9M    632.0K      6.3M   9% /
```

the fourth column is `6.3M` and the rest are choosing different units, what is sometimes called "human" output.  So, we know what they care about is the overlay mount point.  And that at the time someone tested this code it either they didn't try an SDCard of any size or the output of df was different back then, which is why parsing something like df isn't a good idea.

And that's about as far as *I* can take you with any real confidence.  I don't know how overlay is set up on a YUN.

I guess, if you wanted to "fix" the code with a minimal change, it would be to add `-k` to the df command-line to force kilobyte based output, assuming `-k` works on whatever df comes with YUN.  If you wanted to go a step further, I suppose you could use `-P` to get POSIX output from df, again assuming that's supported, and change the expected units in the sketch accordingly.  But if this is **just** for you, and you **know** overlay has more than 1 MB free, you could just as easily change the function so it **cannot** fail:

```cpp
void haltIfInternalFlashIsFull() {
}
```

All that said, I wouldn't be surprised if you run into another problem just like this in another part of the sketch.

Comment: yeah I got an error `err. installing e2fsprogs dosfstools fdisk rsync kmod-fs-ext4` I've hacked away at this yun for a while. Such a headache. Dont know what to do at this point. Thanks anyways

Comment: Given that it will probably be a long drawn out process, I'd steer your toward something interactive like a chat network for forum.  About the only other thing I'll add here is that since most of the sketch seems to be executing shell command-lines on the YUN, you may get better help from people more knowledgeable in OpenWRT than in Arduino.

Comment: Ok I will look in those forums. Thanks Im gonna select your answer because it solved the initital problem I had. Thanks